# How to compute a rectangular credible region from samples

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, credible-interval, highest-density-region

Given high-dimensional Monte Carlo samples $\bf{X_1},...,\bf{X_N}$ from a probability distribution $p({\bf x})$ in $\mathbb{R^d}$, I want to estimate a **rectangular** highest-density credible region for $p({\bf x})$. That is, I want the smallest-volume hyper-rectangle (or "box")

$[{{\bf l}, {\bf u}]=\{{\bf x} \in \mathbb{R^d} ~|~ l_i \leq  x_i \leq u_i \text{ for } i=1,...,n} \} \qquad {\bf l}, {\bf u} \in \mathbb{R}^d$,

such that for a given percentage $\alpha \in (0, 1)$, we have $p({\bf x} \in [{\bf l}, {\bf u}]) \geq \alpha$.

The only dedicated method for estimating such regions (which are sometimes referred to as *simultaneous credible bands*) that I could find is the classic method by [Besag, Green, Higdon and Mengersen (1995)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-10/issue-1/Bayesian-Computation-and-Stochastic-Systems/10.1214/ss/1177010123.full). However, I have tried that method and it performs poorly for high-dimensional or skewed distributions, as it leads to credible regions that are too large and contain all of the samples.

There are also other heuristic methods based on rescaling the bounding box of $\bf{X_1},...,\bf{X_N}$ or the coordinate-wise credible intervals until the resulting set only contains the desired percentage of samples. In my case they work better than the first method, but still not great.

Finally, note that in my case I have cheap access to the density function $p({\bf x})$, while all the approaches listed above do not make use of that. So I expect a density-based approach to perform well, but I could not find an existing method that yields the desired rectangular sets.

I would be extremely interested if anyone knows an efficient, dedicated algorithm for this or could point me to some references.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Ideally, you need the smallest hypercube that contains $\alpha$% of your sample.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a particular method in mind? It appears that finding this hypercube exactly is very difficult, all the methods I could find scale exponentially in the dimension $d$. I thought that there exist more efficient approximate methods that exploit access to the density function, e.g. using the ordering of the samples according to their density.

Comment: Density values do not tell much. Imagine spikes at some values with very little mass nearby.